# Replicate solaris commands in RHEL

Tags: multithreading, performance, bash, solaris, rhel

Are there any equivalent commands such as `pidmax`, `max_nprocs` or `maxuprc` at RHEL? or how can it be developed?, I mean, there must exist a formula, a balance between several variables like memory, cpu and running processes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `pidmax`, look at `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`. I do not think there is any equivalent in default systems to max_nprocs, but LSMs could implement it.